# VBA Object Name

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a very simple task. I have this method when I click the "CommandButton1" in VBA.
I have plenty of this buttons and all have the same type of code. The thing I need is if there is a method to know the object name (in this case "CommandButton1") while I am inside it's own method. There is Me. in here?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

Thanks!
Matías

Comment: `Me.ActiveControl`

Comment: `Me.ActiveControl` would not work if `Me` refers to a worksheet.

Comment: What it seems like you're trying to do is get the CommandButton number to use elsewhere after clicking it. I don't believe that's possible. What I do, and maybe not the best way, is to set a variable for example Public CBNo as integer and then as the first line of code under the CommandButton.
CBNo = (whatever number the CommandButton is) and then call your subroutine using CBNo as the number of the CommandButton selected. Just a thought.

Comment: ```application.caller``` should work, kinda depends on what exactly you want to do with it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller